# Problem opening a text document in python

Tags: python

Namely, I am a beginner in python  the problem is that it doesn't open my text document

```
f=open("C:\Users\goce\Documents\vezba 1\goce.txt")
print (f.read())
```

to open the text document but i get a reply

```
in visual studio 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio
n 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: You can use `raw` strings like this: `f=open(r"C:\Users\goce\Documents\vezba 1\goce.txt")` to defeat unicode encodings.

Comment: Or use forward slashes.  Additionally, perhaps do a bit of research on why a [context manager](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/#working-with-files) should be used to work with files.

Answer (score 3):

In Python strings, the backslash `\` is used as an escape character and as for `\u` specifically it introduces a [Unicode escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) like in "C:**\U**sers.."

the easiest way to get around this is to use a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) by prefixing the string literal with an `r`.

```py
#  Note the r here
#        | 
#        v
f = open(r"C:\Users\goce\Documents\vezba 1\goce.txt")
```

as an alternative you can use `\\` between all folders as in:

```py
f = open("C:\\Users\\goce\\Documents\\vezba 1\\goce.txt")
```

Comment: I added comments to make the `r` extremely visible since you had it bolded and you can't really bold in a code block. If you think the comments are unnecessary feel free to remove them, just wanted to make it clear since you were trying to with the bold I assume

Comment: Many thanks! I am a stackoverflow newbie. The readability is improved now.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read a file that is not in the project folder you need to write r
before the file location like so

```
f = open(r"C:\Users\goce\Documents\vezba 1\goce.txt")
print(f.read())
```

Comment: I have the same problem again                       
 No such file or directory: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\goce\\\\
Documents\\\\vezba 1\\\\goce.txt